# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Model returns null for items not used in a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

**Context**

ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC project

**Issue**

Using a View Model something like this:

```
public class UpdateReturnIssueViewModel
{
    public IssueTrackerIssue Issue { get; set; }

    public bool CloseIssue { get; set; }
}
```

Where IssueTrackerIssue is something like this:

```
public class IssueTrackerIssue
{
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(19)]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 50)]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        public string ReturnCustomerComment { get; set; }
}
```

I fetch data for my View like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult UpdateReturnIssue(int ID)
    {
        // populate the view model in some way

        return View(this.updateReturnIssueViewModel);
    }
```

In my View I only use (i.e. define input asp-for tags for) IssueTrackerIssue.OrderNumber and CloseIssue.

This gets Posted to the controller thus:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult UpdateReturnIssue(UpdateReturnIssueViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Some other processing
    }
}
```

On examining viewModel in the controller I see that everything is null *except* the properties that were used in View.

**Question**

How can I get the full contents of the View Model passed from controller to View and back to Controller intact? Put another way, how can I fully round trip a View Model where some parts of that View Model aren't utilised by the View?

Comment: Have you tried using hidden form inputs?

Comment: One option is using hidden fields.Another option is get the record from the database back when you return to the controller(after the post). Or save it in the session(not good thing but works).

Comment: If you do not need to edit the data in the view, then it would be pointless extra overhead to generate all the extra html to generate from controls, then send it to the browser and then send it all back again unchanged. Just get the data from the database again if you need it in the POST method.

Comment: And the purpose of a view model is to represent the data in the view, View models DO NOT contain data models (that just defeats the whole purpose of using a view model) - they contains the properties of the data model that are used in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There turned out to be two issues to overcome here.

1) As @JoshMein and others kindly pointed out values have to be used on the form else they are Posted back to the controller as null. Using Hidden values overcomes this.

2) My View was a Master - Detail type View and the Detail collection was always returning null i.e. an empty collection. I now realise that this was due to the way I'd coded the iteration of the Detail collection in the View. I was using

```
            @foreach (IssueTrackerIssueComment comment in Model.Issue.Comments)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input asp-for="@comment.ID" type="hidden" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@comment.DateCreated" type="hidden" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@comment.LastUpdated" type="hidden" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@comment.DateCreated" class="form-control" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@comment.Narrative" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button asp-action="DeleteReturnIssueComment" asp-route-id=@comment.ID class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

ASP.NET clearly wasn't able to figure out that these @comment items were bound to the Model so it wasn't passing them back to the Controller.

So I changed the Detail Collection from being ICollection<> to IList<> and used @for instead of @foreach, hence:

```
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Issue.Comments.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.Issue.Comments[i].ID" type="hidden" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.Issue.Comments[i].DateCreated" type="hidden" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.Issue.Comments[i].LastUpdated" type="hidden" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Issue.Comments[i].DateCreated" class="form-control" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Issue.Comments[i].Narrative" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button asp-action="DeleteReturnIssueComment" asp-route-id=@Model.Issue.Comments[i].ID class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Now that @Model is being used to reference these items instead of @comment everything binds nicely and I can see Comments in the controller.

Comment: THANK YOU! you probably save me from hours of debugging

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a way, to pass the values without them being in the form. You can use hidden fields to store the data to be passed back to the server. Here is the razor syntax to create the a hidden field for an existing model field in the form.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.HiddenFieldName)
```

Comment: That works but I note only on elemental properties. My actual IssueTrackerIssue class (i.e. not simplified for this question) contains an ICollection<Comments> which gets used in a table in the View. This is also returned completely as null. The implication is that complex structures can't be passed to a controller. Surely that can't be the case or Master - Detail Views become a real handful.

Comment: @ifinlay In that scenario, I usually do as Leonardo commented above. I pull the record from the database again, and I only set the values for the fields that the user is allowed to edit.

Comment: Ok, which almost gets me a solution. But I'm still struggling with Master-Detail Issue. The ICollection<Comments> gets displayed on the form with an @foreach. I've amended this so that Comments properties that aren't displayed are now hidden. When returned to the controller ICollection<Comments> continues to be null. That's null as in no items in the collection. So I suppose the question becomes "how can you return the Detail elements of a Master-Detail form back to the controller"?

Comment: @ifinlay If you are pulling from the database when you get back to the server, you dont need to assign a new value to the collection. Just let it retain its value and only assign the new values for the fields that could be edited.

Comment: A simpler clarifying example. Let's say a Person class has ID, ForeName, LastName and ICollection<Address>. An Address has ID, Line1 and Line2. My View has Input tags for ForeName & LastName with ID hidden. It also has a @foreach loop with input tags for Line1, Line 2 and Address.ID hidden. Let's say for a particular Person the ICollection<Address> has 3 addresses.  When I Post this back to the controller I get values for ID, ForeName, LastName.  ICollection<Address> however is null. It has zero addresses in it so any address changes are not accessible. Hence I can't make Master-Detail work.

Comment: @ifinlay Check out this article. https://blog.learningtree.com/editing-collections-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Thanks for your continued input. The approach given that the article suggests that, in my simplified example, the repeating Addresses are each treated as a separate form with a controller action specifically to handle a single Address update. So if the user chooses to change say her LastName and two of her addresses in the View they will need to hit Save and await a server response three times. I can't help thinking that there must surely be a way to have the Master and all Detail elements passed to a single controller action via the Model.